# Этимология слова "шкет"

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Очень интересно изучать этимология жаргонизмов и сленга. Вот, например, откуда пошло слово "шкет" в значении "мальчишка", "малолетка", "недомерок"?

Answer (score 3):

~7. шкет (просторечное, бранное, из воровского арго) 'мальчишка, подросток' [13] представляет собой заимствование из чеш. šketa, čketa 'болван, зверь, изверг' [14]. Оставляя открытым вопрос о конкретных путях проникновения данного заимствования, обратим лишь внимание читателя на тот несомненный факт, что целый ряд важных слов разговорно-просторечной сферы, а также более низких стилистических сфер русского словаря заимствован относительно недавно именно из чешского языка. Сюда относятся такие слова, как грубиян, франт, крáля, мандá [15]. Того же происхождения и арготизм шкет.

(Трубачев, [Этимологические мелочи](http://www.philology.ru/linguistics2/trubachev-65.htm))

Comment: Вы уж разберитесь, а то мне тоже интересно, какой ответ считать правильным)))

Comment: Здесь может и не быть правильного ответа. 
Но вообще говоря, ответ grumant'а заведомо неправильный. Во-первых он менял его несолько раз, во-вторых, так и не убедил, что у него есть что-то общее с вопросом.

Что касается его цитаты, то она неуместна. Я цитирую не словарь, а работу Трубачева, посвященную конкретному слову.

Comment: Вы полагаете, что Ваши размышления на далекие от вопроса темы кому-то интересны? Ведь по сути вы так ничего и не сказали... 

Насчет применимости к фене законов фонетики - это Вы, конечно лихо.
Уверяю  вас, там эти законы работают посильнее чем в других случаях.
 Но все равно - мимо кассы. Вы же должны были сначала доказать саму возможность такого перехода, показать путь изменения, а уж потом рассуждать о том, что в данном случае все невозможное - возможно.